# Getting cURL JSON response C++

Tags: c++, json, curl

I would like to know how to get a JSON response with cURL. My current code doesn't work, it just returns an empty string. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've included my current code below.

```cpp
static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int ipCheck(std::string ip)
{
    nlohmann::json j;

    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string response;
    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json"); 

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.ipstack.com/" + ip + "?access_key=SECRET_KEY");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    if (response.empty()) {
        std::cout << "\n\nInvalid request!";
        _getch();
    }
    std::cout << response;

}
```

Comment: You're passing response by value to curl_easy_setopt instead of by pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an error here :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response);
```

you are passing a temporary copy of `std::string` here instead of a pointer to the variable you expect to be passed to the callback so the original variable isn't touched ! worse : the callback is passed a dangling pointer which is the casted to `std::string` and operated on (undefined behavior) so expect to see strange things (usually crash)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what was causing the issue (sorry for the relate reply, but rather late than never)